# NSNumberFormatter not working correctly

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

My code is:

```
NSString *price = @"0.29000";
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[f setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[f setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[f setMinimumFractionDigits:2];

NSNumber * priceNumber = [f numberFromString:price];

[f release];

NSLog(@"priceNumber:%@", priceNumber);
```

The result is:

```
priceNumber:0.2899999999999999
```

Whats going on here? Why not 0.29?

Comment: [It's all about rounding error.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) Also worth reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NSDecimalNumber` class to avoid precision differences like this. With it, you create your `NSDecimalNumber` object directly from the `NSString`, without the need of the `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSString *price = @"0.29000";
NSDecimalNumber *priceNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:price];
NSLog(@"priceNumber:%@", priceNumber);
```

However, if you want to do custom formatting to this `NSDecimalNumber`, you may use `NSNumberFormatter` as well.

Comment: Its actually NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString